# Unable to add custom options

Tags: custom-options

Installed Magento CE 1.6/7/8/9 + sample datas on my dev server

when editing a product in back office, in "custom options" tab, "+ add new option" does not do anything and no JS error logged...

did not find solution in official Magento forums (currently under maintenance)

tried to read official doc about custom options but Google + Magento doc internal search module (I guess it uses Google too) sends me too doc home page, can't access indexed pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found. Came from a module I installed on every version of Magento. Sorry about that, should have think about that at first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload images on the site?  If that's broken too then you may need to update Flash. When you look at the page source for the product admin it loads that section even though it's not visible in the custom-options tab.

Go to: http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/ and reinstall the Flash Player then try it again.

Comment: Hello. Yes I am able tu upload images. Tried to update Flash but did not change anything. Tried with Chrome, FF, IE. :-/

Comment: Download the same version of Magento that you currently have installed.  Copy /app/design/adminhtml/*, /js/*, and /skin/adminhtml/* from the original copy over to your's.

Comment: Did it, did not correct the problem. I will try to install a new fresh Magento 1.9 without sample datas, just to see but it's annoying :(

Comment: Run Magento's Requirements Check to ensure that you're not missing something: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento